# Use of different outputs in a meta-analysis?

Tags: stata, meta-analysis, instrumental-variables

I'm interested in performing a meta-analysis of instrumental variables analyses from a handful of different studies, asking for the same set of model results from all study investigators. However, at the moment I’m not familiar with Stata and the output `ivregress` generates.

Is it possible to use separate outputs to perform a meta-analysis?

Comment: I took the liberty to make your question less dependent upon Stata (shorter title and highlighting of your question in a software agnostic way).

Comment: If you haven't already, you may want to check http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/meta-analysis/ and http://www.stata.com/bookstore/meta-analysis-in-stata/